# Is it possible to keep buttons and imageview aligned for every screen size?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

***Possible Solution at the bottom of the description***

I'm building an app where a have an image with several clickable spots. I'm using buttons over these clickable spots and then make them invisible, so it looks like you are clicking the image. I'm using a constraint layout and several guidelines positioned using percentage of the screen. I though that this way, different screen sizes would not impact the position of buttons and image, since i'm working with percentage and restrained buttons to these guidelines. Turns out that it actually does impact.

I'm adding a screenshot of how I would like for the buttons to look like and how they look after I change the screen size:

[image]

After screen resize:

[image]

P.S.: not all buttons are positioned yet, because I stopped after noticing the problem.

***Possible Solution:***

I kept on trying to come up with a solution to this problem and i might have found one:

Instead of buttons, i'm using imageviews for each part of the image (beams, pilars and slabs) and no image on the background. This way, the plant is actually "drawn" by these imageviews and i have no problem with different screen sizes. I'm still using a constraint layout and guidelines based on percentage.

The problem of this solution is that it's a really boring and long process, but i'm still looking for a better method

Comment: share your XML code - maybe you have done something wrong there

Answer (score 1):

You can give a try to this great library https://github.com/intuit/sdp

It actually provide a new scale unit which is `sdp` (scalable dp).

Comment: I'll give it a try. Thanks!